# Saving FieldIn Django Via API Call

Tags: python, django, api

I'm trying to create a new CustomerDetail object whenever an api is called.But the issue is, Whenever I try to create something for the favorite meal multi-selectfield, I get this error:

```html
MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/customer/favorite_meal/
"'favorite_meal'"
```

This is the api:

```html
@csrf_exempt
def favorite_meal(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

      access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token = request.GET.get("access_token"),
      expires__gt = timezone.now())

      customer = access_token.user.customer

    details = CustomerDetailSerializer(
            CustomerDetails.objects.create(
            customer = customer,
            favorite_mean = request.POST["favorite_meal"]
            ))

    return JsonResponse({"status" : "success"})
```

Here are my models:

```html
class CustomerDetails(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer')

    TYPE = (
    ('Time', (
        ('Breakfast', 'Breakfast'),
        ('Lunch', 'Lunch'),
        ('Dinner', 'Dinner'),
            )),
        )
   
    favorite_meal = MultiSelectField(choices=TYPE)
    interested_in = MultiSelectField(choices=CATEGORIES)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
    completed_orders = models.IntegerField(default = "0", blank=True)
    shares = models.IntegerField(default = "0", blank=True)
    average_order = models.FloatField(default = "0.0", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer.user.get_full_name()
```

In the request, I'm trying to select breakfast and lunch via the api. How would I do this?

Sending Params:

The status says success but, there is no Customer data in details

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MultiValueDictKeyError` error raises when you are trying to access `favorite_meal` from `request.POST`, but the `favorite_meal` doesn't exist in `request.POST`
Try this

```
@csrf_exempt
def favorite_meal(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not 'access_token' in request.POST:
            return JsonResponse({"status": "'access_token' missing in POST payload"})
        access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token=request.POST.get("access_token"),
                                               expires__gt=timezone.now())

        customer = access_token.user.customer

    if not 'favorite_meal' in request.POST and not request.POST["favorite_meal"]:
        return JsonResponse({"status": "'favorite_meal' missing in POST payload"})
    details = CustomerDetailSerializer(
        CustomerDetails.objects.create(
            customer=customer,
            favorite_mean=request.POST["favorite_meal"]
        ))


    return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Postamn screenshot]

**UPDATE**

```
@csrf_exempt
def favorite_meal(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not 'access_token' in request.POST:
            return JsonResponse({"status": "'access_token' missing in POST payload"})
        access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token=request.POST.get("access_token"),
                                               expires__gt=timezone.now())

        customer = access_token.user.customer

    if not 'favorite_meal' in request.POST and not request.POST["favorite_meal"]:
        return JsonResponse({"status": "'favorite_meal' missing in POST payload"})
    for favorite_meal in request.POST["favorite_meal"]:
        details = CustomerDetailSerializer(
            CustomerDetails.objects.create(
                customer=customer,
                favorite_mean=favorite_meal
            ))


    return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
```

Comment: It no longer creates the object.

Comment: Show me the data you are sending

Comment: Updated with photo

Comment: Try with `raw json`.

Comment: How would I select multiple meals? ["breakfast", "lunch"] I can only select one now.

Comment: Yes. I'm not able to put multiple items. It only recognizes one.

Comment: updated the answer...The code expects **always a list of items**. So, you should send `favorite_meal` as **list** always (empty list is also accesptable)